# Why am I getting "Too few arguments to function"?

Tags: c++, function

The code is to calculate the monthly payment of a car. Although I know I am not finished, I wish to see why I am not passing functions correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;


void instructions()
{
  cout << "We will calculate the monthly payment for your particular car." << endl;
  cout << "Please Follow the instructions." << endl;
}



string getCarType()
{
  string carType;

  cout << "Please enter the type of your car: " << endl;
  cin >> carType;

  return carType;
}




double getPurchasePrice()
{
  double purchasePrice;

  cout << "Please enter the price in which you purchased the vehicle: " << endl;
  cin >> purchasePrice;

  return purchasePrice;
}




double getDownPayment()
{
  double downPayment;

  cout << "Please enter the down payment made on the vehicle: " << endl;
  cin >> downPayment;

  return downPayment;
}




int getYears()
{
  int years;

  cout << "Please enter the number of years remaining to pay off the loan: " << endl;
  cin >> years;

  return years;
}





double getRate()
{
  double rate;
  double correctedRate;

  cout << "Please enter the annual interest rate of the loan as a whole number: " << endl;
  cin >> rate;

  //calculations
  correctedRate = (rate/100);


  return correctedRate;
}





double findAmountFinanced(double &purchasePrice, double &downPayment)
{
  double amountFinanced;

  //calculations
  amountFinanced = purchasePrice - downPayment;

  return amountFinanced;
}





double findMonthlyPayment(double &amountFinanced, double &rate, int &years)
{
  double monthlyPayment;
  double sideOne;
  double sideTwo;

  //calculations
  sideOne = amountFinanced * (rate/12);
  sideTwo = pow(1 - (1 + (rate/12)) / (-12*years));
    monthlyPayment = sideOne/sideTwo;


  return monthlyPayment;
}




int findNumberOfPayments(int &years)
{
  int payments;
  payments = 12 * years;

  return payments;
}


int main()
{
  instructions();

  string carType;
  double purchasePrice;
  double downPayment;
  int years;
  double rate;
  double amountFinanced;
  double monthlyPayment;
  int payments;

  carType = getCarType();
  purchasePrice = getPurchasePrice();
  downPayment = getDownPayment();
  years = getYears();
  rate = getRate();
  monthlyPayment = findMonthlyPayment();
  payments = findNumberOfPayments();

  cout << "Make of car: " << carType  << endl;
  cout << "Price Purchased at: " << purchasePrice << endl;
  cout << "Down payment made at purchase: " << downPayment << endl;
  cout << "Years to pay off loan: " << years << endl;
  cout << "Annual rate of interest: " << rate << endl;
  cout << "Your monthly payment is: " << monthlyPayment << endl;
  cout << "The total amount of payments is: " << payments << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Again, my error is that I have too few arguments to function.

Comment: Ex; Declared: `findMonthlyPayment(double &amountFinanced, double &rate, int &years)`, called as `findMonthlyPayment()`, result is compiler complains you're not passing sufficient parameters, which you're not. Wash, rinse, repeat with other calls. What about that isn't understandable?

Comment: Hi, please do not sabotage your own posts. Keep in mind that, once posted, content is licensed here under CC By-SA 3.0.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

In some of the functions like **findMonthlyPayment** you don't pass an argument from the main, whereas these functions expect arguments. You error is self-explanatory you should have debugged it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your method definitions for findAmountFinanced, findMonthlyPayment and findNumberOfPayments, they take arguments when they are called. In your main() function where you calling them, you are not passing any arguments. Hence, too few arguments :)

FYI, a trick to troubleshooting the issue is to look at the complete stack trace of the error message and work your way down through line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you call a certain method and that method have X numbers of arguments or parameters, whenever you call that function in your program you need to call it with exactly the same number of arguments and type of arguments.